# Irrational number and real number definition

Tags: real-numbers, irrational-numbers, square-numbers

Real number - A number which can be represented uniquely by a point on axis.

And real number = rational + irrational number

By this definition, if you take an irrational number such as sqrt(2) ...it's value is non terminating non repeating (1.414....)

Doesnt this violates the def of real number? Since by this way the exact location of the point( sqrt(2) ) can never be identified.

Note: I know that sqrt(2) can be represented on axis using Pythagoras theorem and making a perpendicular of unit length on unit length on x axis. By this way also I can uniquely plot sqrt(2) on axis

But then again this would mean that the decimal expansion of sqrt(2) should terminate at a value.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: While the exact location may never be **identified**, it is still a **unique** point on a number line.

Comment: ""Doesnt this violates the def of real number? Since by this way the exact location of the point( sqrt(2) ) can never be identified."  No.  Just because we can't place it in terms of decimals does not mean we can place it in terms of $\sqrt{2}$.  The square root of two is the length of a diagonal of a unit square.  That is *exact*.  Being able to identify it by it's decimal is not important.  All real numbers and all points on a line are unique.  Or not being able to identify them does not make them not exist.  The real numbers are all points on a line ***whether we can identify them or not***

Comment: "But then again this would mean that the decimal expansion of sqrt(2) should terminate at a value."  No.  Because decimals are not important.  They are not the end all or be all of *anything*.  They are *only* a way of approxiamately with arbitrary (but not absolute) precision.  And they are only *one* way of many of doing that.

Comment: I will point out as well that this definition of real numbers is hardly rigorous since the real number line hasn't yet been defined.  Look up a more rigorous definition using dedekind cuts or cauchy sequences.

Comment: @fleablood thanks for your reply

Comment: @fleablood ... when we say number 3, it means 3.00000 with absolute certainty. When we say 3.5 it means 3.50000 with absolute certainty (unless mentioned otherwise...such as round off etc). Doesn't it seem counter intuitive that we can easily represent sqrt(2) on number line with absolute certainty yet we can't define the decimals with certainty?..

Comment: @ChristopherMarley I agree that it will be a unique point... And that point will not be found with certainty as per you. But when we represent sqrt(2) on axis, we are 100% sure of the location of the point (using Pythagoras theorem). Would like your thoughts on this as well.

Comment: @JMoravitz i would surely look into it. Can you elaborate a bit more though?

Comment: What I am saying is that deciding decimal demarcations is "the" way to determine what a number "is" is faulty.  The real numbers are a continuum and most simply do not fall on any demarcation.  The naive assumption is that we just take smaller demarcations and they'll fit. But that is simply wrong and it is important that we learn and realize that a continuum will never fit any demarcation system. A confusion you are making is thinking defining the number comes first, then the number. It's the other way; numbers exist whether we can define them or not.

Comment: Big Picture: The decimals (I'll call them $\mathbb D$ [this is not standard notation]), which are an *incomplete* subset of the rationals ($\frac 17, \frac 23$ etc. are not in the decimals), so $\mathbb D\subsetneq \mathbb Q$, and the rationals are "dense".  That means if we take two $c,d\in \mathbb D$ so that $c < d$ we can find an $e\in \mathbb D$ so that $c <e<d$ (and if we do this in infinite number of times we can find an infinite number of such decimals between $c$ and $d$). ... to be continued....

Comment: This might seem like not big deal but it is key.  We know that there are "gaps" which no decimals fit but these gaps are infinitely close to decimals.  And there can be a infinite sequence of decimals that get closer and closer to the gaps. (Or they get infinitely closer to a known decimal).  If we take an infinite sequence of $d_1, d_2, d_3, d_4,.....$ so that the the terms get infinitely close together (globally, not sequentially) they "hone in" an a point. Furthmer any "gap" has such a sequence leading to it.... to be continued....

Comment: So big picture.  If we consider these sequences that hone into either a known decimal or hone into an unknown gap we can associate this collection of *sequences* with these "limit points".  And those limits are what the real numbers "really" are.  Now as a consequence, because we have infinited sequences going toward every real point, we can represent every real number with an infinite decimal.  This is usually a good thing.  But ... editorial opinion to come....

Comment: But when we teach that "Every real number is an infinite decimal" and almost paradoxically "Irrational numbers have infinite decimals that never repeat so can't ever be exact" we are enforcing the incorrect idea that somehow the rationals are more well known and precise than the irrationals.  It's *NOT* that the irrationals are not exact.  It's that their exact representation in decimal form is infinite.  Now if you ask a child she'll say "You can't do infinite so that's impossible and it does not exist".  But that's not correct.

Comment: @fleablood thanks for your patience and elaborated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're confusing "represented" and "located". Yes, all real numbers can be represented by the points on a line. But remember that a line is an abstract thing. You can never draw or imagine a line (only represent it approximately). Once you realise these things you should be more clear about this (admittedly deep matter -- check out "continuum").

So, yes, whereas every point on a straight line can be made to correspond to one and only one real number, it does not mean we can always locate this point for all real numbers (by locate I mean using a finite sequence of steps). You may call this theology, but math sometimes often deals in such things, especially in relation to deep matters like this.

The real numbers we can locate are known as constructible numbers. But perhaps even if we allow ourselves more freedom, we may even find rectilinear lengths of any real size and use it to "locate" our points.

But don't think all is settled, or that you can finish settling this in a few hours. It's a very interesting matter that one keeps getting back to.

So how should one think rigorously of real numbers (wlog irrational numbers)? Well, they were defined because extracting the roots and logarithms of rationals does not always give a rational value. But since we know these things must correspond to some quantity, we call them irrationals (this is not very different from the invention of negative numbers and complex numbers). The special thing about irrational numbers is that the involve the "cumulation" of infinitely many operations, loosely speaking. Dedekind was first to give a rigorous definition in terms of order relations and sets (so-called Dedekind cuts).

Comment: Thanks .. I got your point. I would request you to give your inputs of the answer given by me above.

Answer (score 0):

One way to think about this:

Whenever we mention a number on a real number line, we technically are dividing the number line into equal parts and mentioning the value.

For example say a number 10, it means dividing the whole line into equal parts starting from the origin, and the 10th point is your number.

Similarly when we specify the point 0.35 what we actually are doing is that we are further subdividing the number line between 0 and 1, into 20 equal parts, and the 7th part is 0.35 ( 7/20). 
In a very similar way we are representing 0.3 ( which is 3/10...by dividing the number between 0 to 1 into 10 equal parts and the third point is 3/10)..

In a very similar way 2.4 etc etc.

But when we represent sqrt2, etc, we are able to locate the point on a number line ( using Pythagoras theorem).
But there is no such whole number of partitions possible between 1 and 2, out of which one point of that partition will be sqrt(2)... 
Hence the decimal representation goes on till infinity and never terminates nor repeats.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct about the square root of 2 being irrational because the decimal is nonterminating and nonrepeating.  But you are incorrect about the square root of 2 being nonreal.  The square root of 2 is real because it is located on a line connecting the numbers 1 and 2.